# triple vpn tunnel to bypass vpn blocks

Tags: linux, vpn, iptables, tunnel

is it technically possible to setup a VPN tunnel (or port-forwarding,or any other ways) as illustrated with bellow picture ?
Assuming there is an restricted FW which even VPNs do not work plus "help server" bandwidth is low and costly.
So the client requests (packets) should go to the "helper server", then to the "main sever" but coming back directly to the client not through the "helper server"

*by the way, a year ago a read an article about this technique and unfortunately I have forgotten the name of this technique, please inform me if you know the name of this technique*

*please update/edit the title if you found a better one for this scenario*

[image]

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for [Reverse SSH Tunnel](https://goteleport.com/blog/ssh-tunneling-explained/#remote-port-forwarding-reverse-tunneling)?

Comment: @harrymc thanks for the comment, but it is not reverse SSH tunnel if now reverse SSH tunnel